# Возможен ли самомодифицирующийся код на высокоуровневых языках?

Tags: самомодификация

На ассемблере можно написать самомодифицирующийся код. А на python возможно написать такое?

Comment: Так все-таки на любом высокоуровневом, или конкретно на Питоне?

Comment: На С/C++ можно написать такую программу, которая будет модифицировать саму себя в процессе работы.